# How can I find where a specific string is on an image?

Tags: java, python, c, image, image-processing

I was wondering if anyone knew of a way that I could feed an image file to a Python, C or Java program and get back the coordinates of where a specific string appears on the image?

Comment: Why the [tag:java] if you want the code in Python or C?

Comment: It could be in java too, I really don't care what the language is.

Comment: Do you need full OCR (e.g. are you trying to solve something equivalent to a CAPTCHA) or do you know the string (and how it will look, i.e. what font / font size).  If the latter, you still need to do feature finding, but it will be a lot simpler.  As Laurence mentions, OpenCV can do what you want (and has C++ and python bindings (or more specifically, is in C++ and has python and other bindings)

Comment: Basically I know what string I am looking for, I just need to know where on the image it is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I looked into this a bit more. It turns out that [sikuli](http://sikuli.org) does exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

What you're talking about is called [Optical Character Recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition), or OCR.

OCR isn't easy to implement from scratch, but there are libraries out there. [OpenCV can be used for OCR](http://blog.damiles.com/?p=93).